# SwipeRefreshLayout как интегрировать?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Только начал разбираться с приложениями и не могу понять, как сделать мне перезагрузку страницы свайпом вниз . Куда мне надо вставить этот код

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Swipe Example"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

в текущий мой файл, чтобы корректно работало ?

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dip"
    android:paddingRight="0dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip" tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/msw_welcome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/spinner_ring"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/msw_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/msw_progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_style"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(про MainActivity.java пока молчу)

Answer (score 2):

Оберните нужную для Вас `View` или `ViewGroup` в `SwipeRefreshLayout`. После реализуйте в своей активити `SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener` такой интерфейc с методом `onRefresh()`, когда вы будет делать свайп, то будет вызван метод `onRefresh()`, в котором выполняйте нужные для Вас операции.